# jQuery read window width

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I'm trying to write some jQuery that is only run if the window width is below 768px. I have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(window).width() <= 768){
       $("<p>Test</p>").insertBefore( "#menu-item-18 a" ); 
    }

});
```

However I cannot get this to work whether the browser is loaded as <768 or when the browser is resized to <768.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it recognise the window width and run this jQuery only if the browser width is less than <768? Is there a better way to run jQuery based on browser widths?

Example JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/jotq6hwf/

**Edit: having played around more I have discovered this code does run but ONLY when the browser is actively resized. If it is loaded at <768 then the jQuery does not run.**

Comment: I believe that you're looking for `$(window).on('resize', function() {});`

Comment: @silentw I need both the "on resize" and when the window is loaded at that size.

Comment: Can anybody explain why it is "unclear" what I'm asking? What part of the question is unclear?

Comment: You should look at using bootstrap for responsive design http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

No need for jquery.

UPDATED for eventlistener:

```
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', function() {
        alert('attachEvent - resize');
    });
}
else if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        console.log('addEventListener - resize');
    }, true);
}
else {
    //The browser does not support Javascript event binding
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if($(window).width() >= 768){
           $("<p>Test</p>").insertBefore( "#menu-item-18 a" ); 
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: Why have the `.trigger('resize');`?

Comment: So that, on `document.ready`, it triggers the resize event (simulates) so that it calls the code inside.