# Check for existence of particular selector before running - selector created with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm aware that you can easily check any selectors "exist" using .length - however I am having an issue and I believe it is because the particular selector I am looking for is *created using jQuery* - my understanding is that elements that are not loaded at the time of the DOM loading are not selectable using jQuery. Is this correct?

See this code, which does the following:

- Adds HTML before the `#menu-item-18`
- Only if the screen size is less than (or = to) 768px

This works just fine

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if($(window).width() <= 768){
                $('<div class="menu-icon">hello</div>').insertBefore( "#menu-item-18 a" ); 
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

The issue is that as the function constantly checks for the browser width, it constantly inserts the div. You can see this by resizing in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/0uwx28rL/2/

Therefore I want to add a check just before we insert the div, to see if any `.menu-icon` exists. If it does already exist, don't add it.

So I tried the following code, note in this example it uses `.length` to check for `.menu-icon` first and then runs the insert code. But it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/0uwx28rL/3/

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if($(window).width() <= 768){
           if ($('.menu-icon').length){
                $('<div class="menu-icon">hello</div>').insertBefore( "#menu-item-18 a" ); 
            }
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

**How can I get the above code to work?**

**Is there an alternative? How else can I add some custom HTML if the browser width is below 768px, is there a better way?**

Comment: check for $('.menu-icon').length == 0

Comment: If the code from a different question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298175/jquery-read-window-width,  was correct then why haven't you marked it as the right answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to add it if the count is 0 (you are testing for non-zero so it never enters that code):

e.g.

```
if ($('.menu-icon').length == 0)
```

or simply

```
if (!$('.menu-icon').length)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/0uwx28rL/4/

The basic problem was the `length` check, but as `@C Bauer` suggests you would be better off using a unique id for the added element instead of the class. This allows the code to work with existing `.menu-icon` elements (without needed to know how many already existed).

Comment: @Francesca: Second way is my preference (however some coders complain that a single `!` is easily overlooked). :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an Id and check it before deciding to append:

http://jsfiddle.net/0uwx28rL/5/

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        if($(window).width() <= 768){
            if($("#smallMenu").length == 0){
                $('<div id="smallMenu" class="menu-icon">hello</div>').insertBefore( "#menu-item-18 a" ); 
            }
        }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```